# How to make a custom "Add to Home Screen" link on phones

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a website that I am trying to get to save its own custom icon.

So when going on your phone to something such as google.com you then go to the options and "Add to Home Screen" this would then make it as a favorite with a little icon on your phone that when you click will re-open that google.com link.

My question is, is there anyway to make it that you can save an icon image like that to your phone and have a link that goes to a different url. This is for me to create an almost 'fake' way of making an online app that is actually linked to a website.

Comment: I haven't tried this outside the `add2home` plugin, but if you use something like `window.history.replaceState( {} , null, '[target URL]' )` to re-write the navigation bar (provided both URLs are on the same domain), you might get away with it.  Probably asking for trouble though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the phone platform. It is done differently. The user has to do it:
http://www.howtogeek.com/196087/how-to-add-websites-to-the-home-screen-on-any-smartphone-or-tablet/